# Root and ToRadical[Root] do not preserve order of roots

Tags: equation-solving, polynomials

When I look for roots to a quartic polynomial of the form $A - B x^3 + Cx^4$ for positive $A$, $B$, and $C$, it seems that `ToRadicals` does not preserve the root order given by `Root`. Here is a minimal example:

```
In[1]:= Table[ToRadicals[Root[A - B #1^3 + C #1^4 &, k]], {k, 1, 4}]/.{A -> 10., B -> 20., C -> 3.}
Out[1]:= {-0.409172 - 0.660503 I, -0.409172 + 0.660503 I, 0.829652, 6.65536}

In[2]:= Table[Root[A - B #1^3 + C #1^4 &, k], {k, 1, 4}] /. {A -> 10., B -> 20., C -> 3.}
Out[2]:= {0.829652, 6.65536, -0.409172 - 0.660503 I, -0.409172 + 0.660503 I}
```

These are the same roots, in a different order. Can anyone explain this to me? Is it a piece of functionality I don't understand? Or just a bug? I am using version 11.0.1.0 on OS X.

If it is intended functionality, is there any way to predict which root of the function given by `Root` maps to which root of the function given by `ToRadical[Root]`?

Thanks!

-Ben

**Update**

Per J.M.'s suggestion, a cubic example with one parameter:

```
In[3]:= Table[ToRadicals[Root[2 - #1 - 2 #1^2 + a #1^3 &, k]], {k, 1, 3}] /. a -> 1.
Out[3]:= {2. - 1.11022*10^-16 I, -1. - 5.55112*10^-17 I, 1. + 1.11022*10^-16 I}
In[4]:= Table[Root[2 - #1 - 2 #1^2 + a #1^3 &, k], {k, 1, 3}] /. a -> 1.
Out[4]:= {-1., 1., 2.}
```

Comment: Even the cubic case might be enlightening: consider a cubic polynomial with one parameter that can make it have one real root or three real roots (*casus irreducibilis*), and try the same experiments you did.

Answer (score 3):

I was confused by this at first too.  I believe the reason for this behaviour is that the ordering used by `Root` is based on the numerical value of the roots.  Real ones come first, followed by complex conjugate pairs.  Beyond this, they are sorted by real part.

Is there even a consistent way to sort them without taking the numerical value into account?

`ToRadicals` generates an explicit formula in terms of (possibly symbolic) coefficients.  When the coefficients are symbolic, there may not be a way to consistently order the roots without knowing anything about the value of the coefficients.  This is exactly the case in your 3rd order example.  `ToRadicals` will generate three explicit formulas, but which one of these will yield a real value depends on the value of `a`.  Thus this particular list of formulas cannot be ordered.

The documentation even has a similar example about 2nd order equations. Look under Scope.

These expand directly to formulas, even though the coefficients are symbolic:

```
{Root[a #^2 + b # + c &, 1], Root[a #^2 + b # + c &, 2]}
```

$$\left\{-\frac{1}{2} \sqrt{\frac{b^2-4 a c}{a^2}}-\frac{b}{2 a},\frac{1}{2} \sqrt{\frac{b^2-4 a c}{a^2}}-\frac{b}{2 a}\right\}$$

These formulas look a bit different from the "standard" ones.  Writing them in this form ensures a consistent ordering, regardless of the values of `a`, `b` and `c`.  This is not the case with the "standard" formulas:

```
Roots[a x^2 + b x + c == 0, x]
```

$$x=\frac{-\sqrt{b^2-4 a c}-b}{2 a}\lor x=\frac{\sqrt{b^2-4 a c}-b}{2 a}$$

```
% /. {{a -> 1, b -> -3, c -> 2}, {a -> -1, b -> 3, c -> -2}}
(* {x == 1 || x == 2, x == 2 || x == 1} *)
```

`Root` will not automatically expand when there is no consistent ordering.  You can force generating formulas with `ToRadicals`, but then ordering may be lost.

Answer (score 1):

To get the same ordering, consistently apply the replacements for `A`, `B`, and `C` directly to the `Root` objects

```
Table[ToRadicals[
  Root[A - B #1^3 + C #1^4 &, k] /. {A -> 10, B -> 20, C -> 3}], {k, 1, 4}] // N

(*  {0.829652, 6.65536, -0.409172 - 0.660503 I, -0.409172 + 0.660503 I}  *)

Table[Root[A - B #1^3 + C #1^4 &, k] /. {A -> 10., B -> 20., C -> 3.}, {k, 1, 
  4}]

(*  {0.829652, 6.65536, -0.409172 - 0.660503 I, -0.409172 + 0.660503 I}  *)

Table[ToRadicals[Root[2 - #1 - 2 #1^2 + a #1^3 &, k] /. a -> 1], {k, 1, 3}]

(*  {-1, 1, 2}  *)

Table[Root[2 - #1 - 2 #1^2 + a #1^3 &, k] /. a -> 1., {k, 1, 3}]

(*  {-1., 1., 2.}  *)
```